Do ultrasonic sound devices really work for barking problem?
My dog’s barking really annoys me, and he barks sometimes in the middle of the night when I’m deeply sleep. So I’m looking for a solution for this problem. Do ultrasonic sound devices work for barking problem? Please share your expericne.

This are questions about such divices here: https://pets.stackexchange.com/search?q=bark+ultrasonic
